# Spring WebClient odd behaviour

Tags: java, spring, webclient, reactor

I am using the `webClient` to execute an http request using the following code

```java
  @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner() {
        return args -> Flux.just(1)
            .flatMap(__ -> WebClient
                .builder()
                .build()
                .post()
                .uri("http://thisuridoesnotexist/")
                .exchangeToMono(response -> Mono.just(1))
                .doOnError(throwable -> System.out.println("1"))
                .onErrorResume(
                    Exception.class,
                    throwable -> {
                        System.out.println("2");
                        return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("This vanishes"));
                    })
                .onErrorContinue((throwable, o) -> {
                    System.out.println("8");
                }))
            .doOnError(__ -> System.out.println("9"))
            .onErrorContinue((throwable, obj) -> System.out.println("10"))
            .subscribe();
    }
```

The issue actually occurs when the `webClient` is trying to speak with a uri that is not answering and it throws a connection refused exception. As you can see in the code there are multiple `Xerror` operators (which were placed just for the PoC of course ) But the only thing actually working here is the `onErrorContinue` with the `8`. It is expected for the `9` and `10` not to work as the "error" is resolved on the `8` but! if I comment out the `8` then it skips `9` and goes directly to `10`. Lastly no matter the case it goes always skips the `1` and `2` operators.

Reading the documentation of [reactor](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_catch_and_rethrow) and the javadoc above `doOnError` let say, it clearly states that for the `Xerror` operators it cathces **any** exceptions which does not happen here.

Last but not least removing the `onErrorContinue` the `1`, `2` and `9` work as expected. So if the `onErrorContinue` is the issue that just consumes everything eagerly how can I use a "catchAll" failsafe incase an error is not "predicted" on specific cases or its just handled wrong?

just for the completion of the code the pom used in this demo-project is the following

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documented description, it's not Spring's behaviour, but `onErrorContinue`'s:

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#onErrorContinue-java.util.function.BiConsumer-

> Let compatible operators **upstream** recover from errors by dropping the incriminating element from the sequence and continuing with subsequent elements. The recovered error and associated value are notified via the provided BiConsumer. Alternatively, throwing from that biconsumer will propagate the thrown exception downstream in place of the original error, which is added as a suppressed exception to the new one.

...

> Note that onErrorContinue() is a specialist operator that can make the behaviour of your reactive chain unclear. **It operates on upstream, not downstream operators**, it requires specific operator support to work, and the scope can easily propagate upstream into library code that didn't anticipate it (resulting in unintended behaviour.)

So doOnError is not receiving the exception, because the upstream was recovered.

In attempts to understand what it really means and how to deal with it, I made some experiments and have found out, that if you place `throw new RuntimeException()` in block with `8` then `1` and `2` are caught. But not the `9`, because of the same behaviour of `10`